# start new activity on swipe of a image

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, swipe-gesture

I have a layout with image view . On SWIPE LEFT of layout I want to call a new activity.

```
Intent right_intent = new Intent();
right_intent.setClass(this, mainScreenClass.class);
right_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(right_intent);
```

I am able to do this but calling of new activity is taking long pause. Which seems nothing is going on for fraction of second. 
Can i do anything so that swipe of image calls new activity without any time.

Comment: have you thought about using Fragments? That's much better way to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

why do you use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP? this will clear the stack of the activity

Answer (score 0):

Are you using gallery view kind of control, Delay may happen if your downloading images from server and showing that in this imageview so when you swipe an image next image starts loading in next imageview from server. If this is the case you can try to use fragments, So that gallery view and another new activity you calling can be made as separate fragments and can be attached to Single FragmentActivity.

So that while swiping image in single fragment you can replace it with another fragment(your new actiivty contents) or use  `indicator.onPageSelected(arg0)` to keep the another fragment selected(your new activity contents), it will be having somne reduced delay when compared of calling new Actiivty